# Не срабатывает третий цикл

Tags: javascript

Нужно привести к такому виду:

```
> *****
****
***
**
*
**
***
*****
******
```

где n7 это число звездочек.Не работает 3й цикл.

```
function task7(n7) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n7; n7--) {

    for (var j = 1; j < n7; j++) {
      process.stdout.write("*");
    };

    console.log('*');
  };

  var result = "";

  for (var k = 1; k < n7; k++) { // не работает, хотя отдельной функцией работает.
    result = `${result}*`;
    console.log(result);
  };
}
task7(n7);
```

Ведь первые два цикла проходят и доходит очередь до 3го, но он даже не стартуется. Где нарушена моя логика?

Comment: Вы же сами в первом цикле уменьшаете `n7--`..

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался.

Comment: @dm4 добавил в ответе ещё один способ подойти к решению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда дело доходит до 3го цикла n7 равно 0.
Соответственно, цикл не запускается

Answer (score 1):

Ваше же решение чуть короче:

- заранее узнаем число итераций `i = (n - 1) * 2 + 1` и в каждой итерации цикла печатаем звёздочку `len`-раз с помощью метода строки `repeat`
- в конце итерации меняем длину в большую или меньшую сторону с помощью вектора `len += vector`
- разворачиваем вектор с направления уменьшения в сторону увеличения как только достигнем минимума (единичной длины строки со звёздочками) `== 1 && (vector = 1)`

```js
(function(n){
  for (
    let i = (n - 1) * 2 + 1,
        len = n,
        vector = -1;
     i--;
  ) {
    console.log('*'.repeat(len));
    (len += vector) == 1 && (vector = 1);
  }
})(4);
```

Можно сделать ещё проще, если найти формулу зависимости числа звёздочек от номера строки. Для этого повернём голову на 90 градусов вправо глядя на ваш вопрос. Получится примерно такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В глаза бросаются оси OX и OY. Проведём по макушкам звёздочек две прямые: первая из точки `{0, 5}` в `{4, 1}`, а вторая из `{4, 1}` в `{8, 5}`. Теперь найдём [Уравнение прямой, проходящей через две заданные несовпадающие точки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F#%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) для каждой из них.

```
(y1 - y2) * x + (x2 - x1) * y + (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) = 0
```

Для первой получаем `y = 5 - x`, для второй `y = x - 3`, где `x` - номер итерации в вашем цикле, а `y` - число звёздочек для `repeat`-функции. Осталось добавить в цикле проверку на пересечение середины графика. До него используете первую формулу, после - вторую.

Comment: Спасибо!Но до такого мне еще далеко)